# C++: Understanding how memory layout works by printing out addresses?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, virtual-memory, stack-memory

I am trying to understand how C/C++ programs allocate memory. I wanted to see how this works in action and so thought of printing out addresses of locally (stack) and dynamically (heap) allocated variables. The idea is to construct a logical image of the memory (stack and heap) by examining the addresses.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void func() {
    int x = 10; // local(func) variable (stack allocated)
    std::cout << "func: local x @" << (void *)&x
              << " (" << sizeof(x) << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int x = 10; // local(main) variable (stack allocated)
    std::cout << "main: local x @" << (void *)&x
              << " (" << sizeof(x) << ")" << std::endl;

    int y[4]; // local(main) array of ints (stack allocated)
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(y)/sizeof(y[0]); i++) {
        std::cout << "main: local y[" << i << "] @" << (void *)&y[i] 
                  << " (" << sizeof(y[i]) << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    func();
    int *z = new int(10);
    std::cout << "main: heap z @" << (void *)z // heap allocated variable
              << " (" << sizeof(*z) << ") " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "main: local z @" << (void **)&z  // local(main) pointer (stack allocated)
              << " (" << sizeof(z) << ") " << std::endl;
    delete z;
}
```

However I recall that programs do not directly work with physical addresses, but rather with virtual addresses. Just some details: I have an **x86_64 machine**(in which the stack grows downwards I believe) running Linux(Mint) with a **48-bit virtual address space**.

```
$ lscpu
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

, so I get 48-bit (6-byte) addresses as expected in the output of the program, *sorted in descending order by addresses* (**size in bytes in parentheses**):

```
$ ./a.out | sort -k4 -r | column -t
    main:  local  y[3]  @0x7ffe7d0b001c  (4)
    main:  local  y[2]  @0x7ffe7d0b0018  (4)
    main:  local  y[1]  @0x7ffe7d0b0014  (4)
    main:  local  y[0]  @0x7ffe7d0b0010  (4)
    main:  local  z     @0x7ffe7d0b0008  (8)
    main:  local  x     @0x7ffe7d0b0000  (4)
    func:  local  x     @0x7ffe7d0affe4  (4)
    main:  heap   z     @0x5648f749dec0  (4)
```

Based on the above output, I came up with the following image of the memory (mostly just the stack), shown as **blocks of 4 bytes**:

```
                    Stack
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0b001c 
       main:    |   y[3]    | 
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0b0018 
                |   y[2]    | 
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0b0014 
                |   y[1]    | 
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0b0010 
                |   y[0]    | 
                +-----------+ 
                |     ?     |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0b0008 
                |           | 
                +     z     +
                |           |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0b0000 
                |     x     | 
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0afffc
                |     ?     |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0afff8
                |     ?     |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0afff4
                |     ?     |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0afff0
                |     ?     |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0affec
                |     ?     |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0affe8
                |     ?     |
                +-----------+ 0x7ffe7d0affe4 
      func:     |     x     | 
                +-----------+
                    ...

                    ...
                +-----------+ 
                |  new int  | 
                +-----------+ 0x5648f749dec0 
                    Heap
```

As you see with the `?`s I cannot account for certain memory in the stack frame for `main`. I am not allocating any more local variables than the ones displayed so where is this memory going? And that being said, is the approach I've taken even a good way of going about this? **Can the virtual addresses I'm seeing actually be used to paint an accurate picture of the memory during the program's execution?** I'm sure more professional profiling tools exist for this purpose but my aim with this exercise is to see how much info I can glean from a basic program. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Physical addresses are completely hidden from you by the OS, all you'll ever see are virtual addresses.

Comment: The __stack__ grows downwards, __data__ does not. your `z` of size `8` resides in `0x7ffe7d0b0008` up to, including, `0x7ffe7d0b000F`, not down to `0x7ffe7d0b0000`.

Comment: Why are you so interested in memory layout? The actual memory layout of a C++ program can depend on many things including the architecture of your system and even debug or release builds. It is usually not something you can rely on very much. C++ does not require a specific memory layout and it is left up to a specific compiler (and its settings) to create one for you. Exceptions are call layout (stdcall, fastcall etc).

Comment: @PepijnKramer honestly, it was just to see how well the addresses conformed to the diagrams I see everywhere, such as [this one](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs225/fa2022/assets/notes/stack_heap_memory/memory_layout.png).

Comment: I see, well still the content of the stack depends on the actual calling convention being used (and it is not required to use the stack on all architectures). But in general local variables get "pushed" onto the stack.  Moving them forward in (virtual) memory. Also on x86/x64 processors the stack is independent of the memory used for the heap. (it uses its own virtual memory pages).

Comment: Programs can work with physical addresses - in C++. This is very common in FPGA, embedded and IoT

Comment: You don't print out the address of the temporary variable `i` used as a loop control variable and index into the array `y`. Looks like that is 4 bytes since all the other `int` type variables are size of 4. Those question marks above `func` may be saved state such as saved registers and return address for the function call.

Answer (score -1):

To view the layout of the user space you would normally have your linker generate a detailed link map file. The process for doing that depends upon the linker you are using. The approach you are using will likely generate an access violation.

You can also use system services to get information about memory usage.

For the layout of the system space you are either going to have to use the system documentation for your operating system or you are going to have to become a kernel mode commando.

What you are trying to do is not really very useful because you are not really seeing memory allocation in action in such a program. There is no difference between "stack" and "heap" when it comes to memory allocation. The only difference is how they are used. Stack and heap look the same.

In a system you are going to have memory that is
Readonly/Execute  Code
readonly/Noexecute  Static Data
Read/write/Execute    Generally avoided
read/Write/Noexecute   Stack, heap, static variable